# How to test a HTTP POST of Spring MVC using a web browser?

Tags: testing, spring-mvc, browser, http-post

How can I test an HTTP Post using a web browser?

The controller I'm trying to test is an Spring MVC controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean manual testing, then use a browser extension, such as [RESTClient for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/).

For automated testing, have a look at [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yes, I want a manual testing. Do you know one for Google Chrome?

Comment: @mohamede1945: Not offhand, no.  Should be easy to find one.

Comment: Yes, I find Simple REST Client! Thank you very much